# Codeigniter view returns null with json_encode

Tags: php, ajax, json, codeigniter, view

I've got a big Problem with Codeigniter 3.0.
So JQuery makes an Ajax Post to the Server. The CI controller is working. After that, CI needs to send a json back to the client.

client:

```
$.post('/update_uri',{var:val},function(return){
      console.log(return);
})
```

On the CI Controller (/update_uri):

```
$result['pageX'] = $this->load->view('pageX','',TRUE);
print_r($result); //This is working
echo json_encode($result); //This isn't working
```

With `json_encode($result)`, an empty String arrives on the client, and I don't know why.
With `print_r($result)` the console.log command displays the view as it should.

Can somebody confirm this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `json_encode` fails because it expects an array, and youre providing it a string. Read up on `json_encode` and its options: `JSON_HEX_QUOT, JSON_HEX_TAG, JSON_HEX_AMP, JSON_HEX_APOS, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT, JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE.`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: why not just `echo` the result to your ajax, and use js to display the HTML? no need to `json_encode`

Comment: Hi folks, I found the Issue. It's because json_encode needs an utf8 string. So this works: $result['pageX'] = utf8_encode($this->load->view('pageX','',TRUE))